# Efficient way to Query Large lists to get little data

Tags: 2013, caml-query, large-lists

I am querying a large list with around 25000 items but the data returned is quite small, like 20 items top. 
Can you please let me know the best practices to do so, for e.g. orderby Indexed column.

I am currently using `viewfields` and `rowlimit`. Would love to know if `orderby` helps!
There's something interesting about caching of data returned, not sure about it though!

As data returned is small I don't think `contentIterator` will help. I tried the time to execute query with it and without it, doesn't improve.

Comment: I would suggest ContentIterator should be helpful.. Use query.ListItemCollectionPosition

Comment: it helps when data returned is high

Comment: Can you tell what you mean by TOP 20, most recent modified or created 20 ?

Comment: it meas the highest number of items returned would be 20